# Sequence to Sequence Learning with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

I was trying to implement a sequence to sequence learning task in Keras.
I want the model to learn the following transformation. 
F(X) -> Y 
Where X is

```
  [[0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

and Y is given by

```
  [[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

Each ***column*** in the X and Y array represents a word in a sentence. However, each word has ten features in the input sequence (i.e X) and just five features in Y. I tried implementing a model with the following code.

```
model = Sequential()
LAYER_NUM = 3
HIDDEN_DIM = 900
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, return_sequences=True), input_shape = (None, 10)))
print("YEAH!")
for i in range(LAYER_NUM - 1):
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

However, this raised the following error.

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_3 to have
>   shape (10, 5) but got array with shape (5, 10)

Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error gives it away. You said *columns* represent the words, in the Keras model you have it would be **rows**. So you have to transpose your data `X.T` and `Y.T` to fix it.